# Is it important to know specific bump functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f(x)= e^{\frac{1}{|x|^2 -1}}$ if $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $|x|\geq 1$.

Then, $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and this shows that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has an element whose integral is not zero.

And this fact can be used to show $C^c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ version of Urysohnn's lemma.

My question is that, is it useful to know an explicit example of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to analyze $L^p$ space and others? What is an example that an explicit bump functions in $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ being useful? Or the above $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ version of Urysohn's lemma can handle everything?

Comment: Sometimes the fact that $f$ is radial symmetric is also quite useful.